# How to write a unit test for a React component that measure its rendering time?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to come up with a solution for measuring my component's rendering time. I know about React Profiler, but I'm looking for something that can be included as part of the component's test suite, not a manual test. I think I could use timers but that seems a bit fragile. Ideally someone would know about something more robust. I use Enzyme + Jest for unit testing.

Thank you

Comment: What is the time that was measured with *fake* Enzyme renderer and *fake* Jest DOM supposed to tell you? If you want profiling to be automated, take a look at headless browsers - Playwright, Puppeteer, etc.

Comment: I want to monitor a component that has the potential to be slow because it deals with a lot of data. As I implement new features I want to monitor the rendering speed to find out any issue before it goes to production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's something you should probably avoid testing. Performance tests should not be part of unit tests. I do recommend keeping your jest for unit testing and your profiler with measuring for performance.